# Dialog _ jQuerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to open the dialog box based on the Ajax result.
How to create/open the dialog from the .js file?

Anyone help me.

THanks in advance.

Comment: just a tip: put up an example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just link to a file like this:

`<a href="foo.html" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>`

it's done with AJAX anyway **and degrades nicely** for people with lesser JS support.

The way you want to do it:

Create a wrapping div for your content and give it a `data-role=dialog` attribute, then call `.dialog()` on it, or `.page()` if dialog doesn't work.
update:
With JQMbeta2 they introduces a 'create' event which you have to trigger it on stuff instead of using .page

Comment: just a tip: put up an example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.org

Comment: When somebody asks a question and wants more people to understand what he wants it's good to give them a [not]working example. It's even more valid when the problem is described with one sentence. Whereas an answer I provide is my experience for the OP. I don't have to do everything for him. If he has no idea how to get it done he can always ask in comments. It's not my duty to post a ready solution for somebody's work. And what you posted here is not a good [nor polite] way to say "help, I still have no idea"

Comment: Caution: this method works fine if you're planning on externalizing the dialog in a separate file (here: foo.html). But if you want to embed the dialog in the same file as the page you will need to use the id of the dialog in the button anchor href.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this post is still relevant, but I did it like this:

```
function openDialog(strPageId, strTransition){
    $.mobile.changePage($("#"+strPageId+":jqmData(role='dialog')"), {transition : ""+strTransition+""});    
}
```

And then you can invoke it on a button, or in your code, wherever...

```
<button data-theme="a" name="btnOS" id="btnOS" onClick="openDialog('pu-edit-mailorder','slideup')">Order</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me (in b1): I get "cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined".

Comment: Same for me. I guess it was not a standard way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think he means he wants to use JS to open a jQM dialog, not create a dialog link and fire a click event.

If so you're supposed to use $.mobile.changePage('pageURL', {role: 'dialog'});

Comment: Can you use a jqm dialog to ask the user if he is sure to submit a form?

Answer (score 0):

`.dialog()` for some reason did not work for me. I am using:

```
$("<a href='#dialog-id' data-rel='dialog'></a>").click().remove();
```

Not really nice, but works.