# HTML5 Popup dialog jQuery code not working with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a Popup dialog to an Html5 mobile template built with jQuery mobile, this code it's not working. When i press "Click me" button nothing happen.

i tried several navigators and incognito mode also.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Dialog Example - Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="MyDialog" title="Hello World dialog">
      <p>This is My Hello World dialog.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Button lunch dialog -->
   <button id="openDialog">Click  me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    // Apply dialog to MyDialog id
    $( "#MyDialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
    });
    // Attach a click event to the button with id openDialog
    $( "#openDialog" ).click(function() {
      $( "#MyDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Html5 WebView Android App.

Comment: "Not working" is pretty vague. Can you explain what's not working?

Comment: When i press "Click me" button nothing happen.

Comment: Did it ever work? You really should provide more detail in question!

Comment: Also have you tried researching first? Try Your question site:jsfiddle.net to try and find working demos or just search google.com

Comment: Yes i do some research and find nothing.

Comment: Try browsing these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile

Comment: Try seeing this also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: While there is a [jQuery Mobile Dialog Widget](https://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/) (depreciated/removed in later versions), your code seems to reference the [jQuery UI Dialog Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) instead (the "open" method and "autoOpen" option). For reference, see the [jQuery Mobile Dialog example here](https://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/#entry-examples).

Comment: These might be helpful: [Creating a dialog JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101370/creating-a-dialog-jquery-mobile) and [How to open a jQuery Mobile Dialog from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230460/how-to-open-a-jquery-mobile-dialog-from-javascript)